# Command Errored Exit Status 1: - Pytorch Object Detection

Tags: python, git, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.curiousily.com/posts/object-detection-on-custom-dataset-with-yolo-v5-using-pytorch-and-python/) to learn how to run my own object detection, but I am running into an error that I can't seem to fix. I found a solution on some git hubs issues pages. They suggested running: `!pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git`, but I still get the same error. I am using Google Colab. Any suggestions?

**input:**

```
!pip installgit+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
```

**output:**

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
  Cloning https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-u21a5wjs
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git /tmp/pip-req-build-u21a5wjs
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: so do you want to add cocoapi dataset into your google collaboratory

Comment: yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is written in https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi

> To install:
> For Python, run "make" under coco/PythonAPI

So you cannot do pip install even in local.
Follow these steps in your google colaboratory to install,

```
!git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
# by default you are in /content in google colab use !ls to check
!ls
cd cocoapi
!ls
# you will see these,  common   license.txt  LuaAPI  MatlabAPI  PythonAPI  README.txt  results
cd PythonAPI
!make
!make install
```

Now your cocoapi github repository is installed and is ready to use.
As a sample code to test you can try these lines, it should show no errors.
`from pycocotools.coco import COCO`